# Hadoop: How to save Map object in configuration

Tags: hadoop

Any idea how can I set Map object into org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serialize your map into JSON and then put it as string in your configuration.
There is no way to put a whole object into it, because the whole configuration will be written as a XML file.

GSON is quite good at it: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
Here is the tutorial about how to serialize collections: http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples