# How do we pass objects of some custom class as a parameter to mapper in mapReduce programs??

Tags: hadoop

How do we pass objects of some custom class as a parameter to mapper in mapReduce programs?? 
JobConf has 'set' methods for boolean, string, int and long. What if I want to pass a Document object as a parameter to my mapper? Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I have given a tip to someone who wanted a whole map to pass to a mapper.

[Hadoop: How to save Map object in configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807576/hadoop-how-to-save-map-object-in-configuration)

The idea is the same, you have to serialize your object into a string and put it into the configuration. JSON works very well, because the configuration is serialized as XML, thus having no problem while deserializing.

Comment: Yes, even I do the same way and can pass full readonly small tables as jobconf.addString(key,jsonvalue) and has worked well.

Answer (score 1):

If your object implements Writable, you can serialize it to a Byte array, base64 encode the byte array and then save off the resultant string to the configuration. To decode do the opposite.

Of course, i wouldn't recommend this if your object has a very large footprint - in this case you're better off serializing it to a file in HDFS and using the distributed cache.

Comment: And the question is, how to pass the base64 deserializer to the mapper so you can deserialize the object ?

Comment: @Adio couldn't you just import it from the mapper?